# How to see system call that executed in current time by process?

Tags: linux, strace

Linux utility "strace" show the list of syscall that started after run of strace. How I can see syscall that run in current moment by process? before start of strace.

Comment: You open a console window and start typing /usr/sbin.... dang the current time is over, it's already the next moment! Missed it! Next time start a couple of moments earlier than the current time!

Comment: I agree. I will reformulate my question: how to see the system calls that are currently being executed by the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`proc` offers some information about what the kernel is currently doing "for" a process

`/proc/${pid}/syscall
/proc/${pid}/stack`

More information:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html
- http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2013/02/21/peeking-into-linux-kernel-land-using-proc-filesystem-for-quickndirty-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you know the PID of the of process, you can simply use strace to track all the syscalls being made in realtime.

`strace -p PID`

Answer (score 1):

You find that out using `ps`:

```
ps -p PID_OF_PROC -ocmd,stat,wchan
```

The `wchan` is the key here. From `man ps`:

> **wchan       WCHAN**     name of the kernel function in which the process is sleeping, a "-" if the process is running, or a
> "*" if the process is multi-threaded and ps is not displaying threads.

---

> **PROCESS STATE CODES**
> Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe
> the state of a process:
>
> ```
>            D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>            R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>            S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>            T    stopped by job control signal
>            t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
>            W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>            X    dead (should never be seen)
>            Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
>
>   For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
>
>           <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>           N    low-priority (nice to other users)
>           L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
>           s    is a session leader
>           l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
>           +    is in the foreground process group
> ```

Comment: Useful, but kernel function and syscall are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @GL2014 True, but this is all you can get from ps.

Comment: PS: Just saw the accepted answer in this thread, looks like that's the way to go

Comment: wchan is the top frame of what is shown in /proc/pid/stack (when the process is not in TASK_RUNNING state)